# aws-iam-autenticator problem when downloading go client libary

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, kubernetes, aws-sdk, amazon-eks

I'm trying to connect to AWS EKS cluster using lambda written with Go.

My import looks like that:

```
  import (
        "encoding/base64"
        "fmt"
    
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/awserr"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/eks"
        "github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/pkg/token"
    )
```

My actual code which requires import of `github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/pkg/token` package is the following:

```
gen, err := token.NewGenerator(false)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

However, when I'm using `go get` command, I'm getting this error.

```
go get github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/pkg/token
go: found github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/pkg/token in github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator v0.5.1
go get: github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator@v0.5.1: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: sigs.k8s.io/aws-iam-authenticator
                but was required as: github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator
```

and I'm not able to workaround it. Can you help?

Comment: As the error says, you are using the wrong import path for `aws-iam-authenticator`, try the suggested one.

Comment: If import is from the docs, worth posting as an issue to https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/issues

Comment: @Marc, but I',m importing github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/pkg/token aws-iam-authenticator is obviously one of internal imports.

Comment: And the import path is wrong, it's "sigs.k8s.io/aws-iam-authenticator/pkg/token` as the error message clearly states.